I'm trying to add and remove widgets in response to if statement
So the first big coding project ever. I'm trying to make a phone app in kivy for fun. Currently, I'm really stuck trying to get a function to work the way I want.
I have a function where "def climbtype" outputs a value that can be read by an statement. I wanted this statement to change the "grade" widget to the "Sport_Spinner_widget". But every time I try to it gives me.
"File "kivy\\properties.pyx", line 964, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'. Did you mean: '__setattr__'?"

error. I know it is target code for "def add_sport_grades(self):" that is the issue but i have no idea how to sort it.
Any help would be appreciated. If I need to clarify any please let me know.
.py file
from kivy import Config
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

class ClimbWidget(BoxLayout):
  def remove(self):
    self.parent.remove_widget(self)

  def climbtype(self, value):
    if value == "Sport":
      self.add_sport_grades()

  def add_sport_grades(self):
    customewidget = ClimbWidget()
    sportspinner = Sport_Spinner_widget()
    self.ids.grade.add_widget(sportspinner)  # still not functioning?????!!!


class LogClimb(Screen):
  def add_climb_inputs(self):
    customewidget = ClimbWidget()
    self.ids.container.add_widget(customewidget)

  class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


kv = Builder.load_file("LogBook.kv")


class LogBook(App):
  def build(self):
    return kv


LogBook().run()

.kv file
LogClimb:

<LogClimb>:
    name: "LogClimb"
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: 0.1
        pos_hint: {"y" : 0.9}
        Label:
            text: "log Climb"
        Button:
            text: "Add Climb"
            on_press: root.add_climb_inputs()
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        size_hint_y: 0.9
        size_hint_x: 2
        id: container

<ClimbWidget>
    height: 40
    size_hint_y: None
    Label:
        text: "date"
    Spinner:
        id: climbtype
        text: "Climb type"
        values: ["Sport", "Boldering", "Trad"]
        on_text: root.climbtype(climbtype.text)
    TextInput:
        id: climbvenu
        text: "Venue"
        font_size: "20dp"
        multiline: True
        #on_text_validate: root.on_text_validate(self)
    Spinner:
        id: "grade"
        text: "grade"
        font_size: "20dp"
    Button:
        text: "-"
        on_press: root.remove()

<Sport_Spinner_widget>:
    height: 40
    size_hint_y: None
    Spinner:
        text: "hi"
        values: ["1", "2", "2+", "3a", "3b", "3c", "4a", "4b", "4c", "5a", "5b", "5c", "5c", "6a", "6a+"]

I have tried changing the target to the "self.ids.container.add_widget(customewidget)" in "class LogClimb(Screen)" a pathway I know works but to no avail.

Please post a [mcve].

You need to remove the Spinner widget and then add the Sport_Spinner_widget to the correct place. Since you didn't include the definition of Sport_Spinner_widget in your post, I created a simple definition:
class Sport_Spinner_widget(AnchorLayout):
  pass

Also, using a string as an id makes it very complicated to use. In your kv, replace:
id: "grade"

with:
id: grade

And then modify the add_sport_grades() method to do the remove and replace:
def add_sport_grades(self):
    # customewidget = ClimbWidget()
    self.remove_widget(self.ids.grade)  # remove the spinner
    sportspinner = Sport_Spinner_widget()  # create the new Sport_Spinner_widget
    self.add_widget(sportspinner, index=1)  # add the sportspinner widget at the correct index

Note that after this is executed the grade id will be invalid.
